# How to change PHP Login text into Link?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ipb

In my site [ebaysecrets.co.il](http://ebaysecrets.co.il) my users have the option to see the content without be enable to comment unless they login.

It looks like that:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2Jsw.png

Now it display like a Normal Text desplayed and not a Link, and I want to convert it into a Link.

The Code is like that:

Under **skin_forum** I have the **forumIndexTemplate** that have the following code:

```
<if test="usercanpost:|:$forum_data['_user_can_post']">
    <li>
        <a 
            href='{parse url="module=post&amp;section=post&amp;do=new_post&amp;f={$forum_data['id']}" base="publicWithApp"}' 
            title='{$this->lang->words['topic_start']}' 
            accesskey='s'>{$this->lang->words['topic_start']}
        </a>
    </li>
<else />
    <li class='disabled'>
        <span>
            <if test="isGuestPostTopicTop:|: ! $this->memberData['member_id']">
                {$this->lang->words['forum_no_start_topic_guest']}
            <else />
                {$this->lang->words['forum_no_start_topic']}
            </if>
        </span>
    </li>
</if>
<if test="moderationDropdownLink:|:$this->memberData['is_mod'] == 1">
    <li class='non_button'>
        <a href='#' id='forum_mod_options' class='ipbmenu'>{$this->lang->words['forum_management']}</a>
    </li>
</if>
```

I try some changes like this:

```
<li class='disabled'>
    <span>
        <if test="isGuestPostTopic:|: ! $this->memberData['member_id']">
            <a href="index.php?app=core&module=global&section=login">
            {$this->lang->words['forum_no_start_topic_guest']} 
        <else />
            {$this->lang->words['forum_no_start_topic']}
            </a>
        </if>
    </span>
</li>
```

But without success!

What is the correct syntax I need to insert so it will work as a Link pointing to this:

> ebaysecrets.co.il/index.php?app=core&module=global&section=login

?

Comment: There isn't an `<if>` tag in html, so what you're trying to do won't work. You'll need to perform the if statement in PHP (or whatever language you're using to log the user in).

Comment: What kind of framework are you using? It looks like "pseudo"-HTML that wraps PHP code into HTML? But why?

Comment: The site appears to be running Invision Power Board forum software. Perhaps their support forums may be able to help.